# Math homework guidance - mean probability distribution

Tags: probability

95% of people must queue at a shopping line in a supermarket for 30 seconds before being able to continue. What is the distribution mean of the number of people among 20 randomly selected people who must queue at the shopping line before being able to continue. To solve Use the table and then use the formula of the mean of probability distribution.

What I have done so far is found that $p = 0.95$ and the sample size $n=20$ but I'm kind of stuck what table to use and how to proceed is it the z table? I would appreciate help on how to proceed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean "What is the **mean** number of people among 20 randomly selected people..."?

We're not supposed to do your homework, but recall the mean of the Binomial RV...

EDIT: ok I think I can understand what your prof meant. (S)he probably wants you to find the mean *directly* using formula $E(X) = \sum xp(x)$. For this, you should use the Binomial table.

Comment: No I don't want anyone to do my homework but I just need to know what table the question is referring to so I can proceed. It says what is the mean of the distribution of the number of people among 20 randomly selected people that must wait at the queue

Comment: I know using the binomial formula I would multiply the p by 20 but the question must be solved using the table

Comment: Okay and would it be the sum of each x value using the binomial table multiplied by the p eg. For x=1 it's 0.95x0.3774

Comment: When the table only has 7 x values for the distribution I need do I assume the rest of the x values are equal to zero?

Comment: is it probability table or CDF table? If the values are missing, you may assume them being trivial.

Comment: No it's probability function table, the tables were not provided by the prof. So I'm kind of confused I searched binomial table but there are different tables with different values is it this table http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~olgac/stab22_Winter_2014/datasets/Binomialtable.pdf

Comment: Here, use $p=0.05$ and find the mean number of people *not* in a queue.